# Rails - problema con il salvataggio di un array tramite check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a register for a school, I got to the point where I had to create the class lessons and save presences/absences in it.
I'm thinking about making appear a collection_check_boxes which gathers all the students who belong to the class we are recording the lesson for.

At this point the checkbox is properly displayed on the vista, but it doesn't fill the array student_id of Lesson when it's created.

Il controller

```
  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
    @group_id = params[:group_id]
    @students = Student.where(:group_id => @group_id)
  end
  def create
    @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.save
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson, notice: 'Lesson was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lesson }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:date, :starts_at, :finishes_at, :materials, :areas, :homework, :group_id, :student_id)
    end
```

While the view that calls the check_boxes

```
  <div class="field">
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes :student_id, Student.where(:group_id => @group_id).order(name: :asc), :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
  </div>
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :student_ids, Student.where(:group_id => @group_id).order(name: :asc), :id, :name %>
```

Comment: undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol

Comment: I dropped `:lesson` as first parameter to `collection_check_boxes`. Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

ok, i solved

I had to declare the array between the parameters allowed in the controller

```
def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:date, :starts_at, :finishes_at, :materials, :areas, :homework, :group_id, :student_id => [] )
    end
```

i hope this can help someone else.